# Which is better CRUD coding style using Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, coding-style, redux, single-page-application

I have a simple question about coding style for single page application. My front end is using **React Redux**

For example I have a standard CRUD page where data is displayed in table and pop up modal form. Data table is filtered from the server not from the client.

**My question :** If i create, update or remove a data should I call a refresh function or just edit it in redux store?

**Refresh function :**

1. Data always updated
2. Newly added data is filtered
3. Two times request, slower, unresponsive **(Main problem)**

**Redux store:**

1. App looks responsive
2. One time request
3. Lost server side filter function and data is not updated if multiple users is using the app **(Main Problem)**

Any advice will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dispatch an async action which queries the server where filter happens and when it resolves, update redux state with the refreshed, filtered data.

Pseudocode

```
// dispatches an action to refresh data without page reload
export function refreshDataAction() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {

    return (
      fetch('api/data', options) // fetch the data from server and let it filter
      .then(data => dispatch(updateDataAction(data)))
    );
  };
}

// dispatches an action to update redux state with filtered data
export default function updateDataAction(data) {
   return { 
     type: 'UPDATE_DATA',
     ...data,
   }
}
```

---

**Then you could just call** `dispatch(refreshDataAction())`. **Data is filtered, no page refresh.**

Comment: So that will be two times request? the refresh function I mean is actually an API call to refresh the data.

Comment: yes, but not page reload. It will be a single request.

Comment: Why single request? I think it will be two times, create(...).then({refresh()})

Comment: oh yes, if you also create before refresh that are 2 requests, but you can't avoid them anyways. Why are you so worried about doing requests as long as your page doesn't reload it's ok. I think you might be trying to optimize at the wrong place.

Comment: always glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Edit the store locally to give immediate feedback, then send the request and when you get the reply back consolidate the store with the new data

basically, do both things and get the best benefit of both worlds

Comment: How about the filter? let's say the data is sorted by name, and has pagination with 10 items/page.
If i added a new data which name should be in another pagination page, then I cannot edit the store unless I have extra filtering function. Filter is done server side

Answer (score 0):

Calling refresh in a React application (not only React, but any real-time front-end app) kind of defies whole principal of using React.

What you should do is, whenever there occurs a data-changing operation in your client, you should trigger an API call, that alters your server-side data accordingly. Send the data back to the client (you can send it to all clients, if you fancy web-socket), save it to the Redux state to trigger a re-render.